# Bi-differential operators in the definition of star product in deformation quantisation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, quantization, formality

Let $X$ be an (affine) Poisson variety (not necessarily smooth) over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 (such as $\mathbb{C}$), denote $\mathcal{O}(X)$ its ring of functions and $\{-,-\}$ its Poisson structure. A deformation quantisation of $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is by definition $\mathcal{O}(X)[[\hbar]]$ with a star product. A star product $\star$ on $\mathcal{O}(X)[[\hbar]]$ is a $\mathbb{C}[[\hbar]]$-bilinear associative unital (with unit the constant function 1) map $\mathcal{O}(X)[[\hbar]]\times\mathcal{O}(X)[[\hbar]]\to\mathcal{O}(X)[[\hbar]]$, such that $f\star g=fg \mod \hbar$. Therefore there is a sequence of map $\phi_i:\mathcal{O}(X)\times\mathcal{O}(X)\to\mathcal{O}(X)$ with $$f\star g=fg+\sum\limits_{i\geq 1} \hbar^i\phi_i(f,g)\in \mathcal{O}(X)[[\hbar]]. (\textbf{S1})$$ such that $\phi_1(f,g)-\phi_1(g,f)=\{f,g\}.$

One usually also requires that: $\phi_i$'s are bi-differential operators (i.e., that $\phi_i(a,-),\phi_i(-,b)\in Diff(\mathcal{O}_X)$ for all $a,b\in \mathcal{O}_X$), and it is usually part of the definition of a star product. It is well-known in the smooth case that every deformation quantisation is gauge equivalent to one that $\phi_i$'s have the bi-differential operators property. This is probably why we can include this property in the definition. For example, see Theorem 0.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111094.pdf by AMNON YEKUTIELI. I want to ask, is the same statement also true in the non-smooth case.

Comment: Can you include more details: Are you saying that every $*$-product that is bilinear etc defined as in $S1$ are induced by such differential operators $\phi_i$? What is a bidifferential operator in your language?

Comment: @hm2020, hi, see the edit